# is it possible to define multidim arrays with #define directive in pure C?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I want to manage my packs of string constants separately from the computational code. **I want to do it in separate file.**

So, I need to create a multidim array of strings and conclude it under a `STR_PACK_X`.

If it is possible, can anyone route me right way with `#define` multidim-string-constants syntax?

Help me please, what's wrong with that attempt:

```
#define STR_PACK_X \
({ \
\ // comm1
    { "string1", "string2", "string3" }, \
\ // comm2
    { "string11", "string22", "string33" }, \
\ // comm3
    { "string111", "string222", "string333" } \
})
```

I want to use it like that:

```
int line_lim = 4, word_lim = 4, char_lim = 50;

if (flag1)
{ 
  char array[line_lim][word_lim][char_lim] = STR_PACK_1; 
  /* array processing */
  ... 
}
if (flag2)
{ 
  char array[line_lim][word_lim][char_lim] = STR_PACK_2; 
  /* array processing */ 
  ... 
}
```

Comment: You need an initializer for your array. That mustn't start with a `(`. Also there mustn't be any character after the line continuation ` \\` . => Remove the `// ...` and the brackets... BUT that only works for normal arrays, not for VLA, as you cannot initialize a VLA.

Comment: General note: You probably get some compiler warning. For any question on SO please show the exact error messages you get.

Comment: I would imagine your *compiler* would be telling you what, if anything is wrong with this (apart from the semi-obvious problem of using a screwdriver to pound nails). Single-line comments buried in a massively-line-continued macro is a recipe for failure, for sure. And note, there is no `STR_PACK_1` or `STR_PACK_2`, so I'm betting I'm not getting the same errors you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple issues:

1. You want to create an initializer list. For arrays this has to look like this: `int arr[] = { ... }` while your replacement text puts everything into additional brackets `({ ... })`. That only produces one single value, not an array.
2. In macros, the replacement can be continued on the next line by putting a `\` as last character in the line. No characters (also no comments) shall follow afterwards.
3. The issues above arise when you want to initialize a normal array with constant dimensions.
   What you have is a variable length array (VLA). These cannot be initialized at all.

Comment: thank you, you make it more clear for me than i expected. I didn't think about VLA when posted, in my real case array fields size will be constant.

Comment: @MkKvease In that case simply drop the macro and create a const look-up table containing all the strings? The bounds in your example doesn't match so you need a way to deal with that, `_Static_assert` etc.

Comment: @Lundin how can i do that in separated files without macro? is it a good idea to create const-table in a header-file?  I am bad at good practices..

Comment: @MkKvease For read-only tables, it's usually acceptable to declare them in a .c file then expose them with `extern` in the corresponding header file. Otherwise in case `extern` is outlawed by your coding standard (it often is), you can write a getter/look-up function.

Comment: @Lundin I got your idea! thanks, it will be useful for sure, when I get to a stage of project restructuring.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, you have several language violations here:

- Parenthesis around an initializer list isn't valid, it gives the wrong syntax for what you wish to achieve.
- You can't initialize a variable-length array.
- You can't place characters after a `\` line wrap, using `//` comments together with them is always problematic. I'd advise to indent all `\` to a fixed source column.

It would seem that instead of an initializer list, you are rather looking to use a *compound literal* and then copy the contents from that one in run-time:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STR_PACK_X                                          \
(const char* [3][3])                                        \
{                                                           \
    { "string1",   "string2",   "string3"   }, /* comm1 */  \
    { "string11",  "string22",  "string33"  }, /* comm2 */  \
    { "string111", "string222", "string333" }, /* comm3 */  \
}

int main (void)
{
  int line_lim = 4, word_lim = 4, char_lim = 50;
  char array[line_lim][word_lim][char_lim]; // VLA, can't be initialized

  for(size_t i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    for(size_t j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
      strcpy(array[i][j], STR_PACK_X[i][j]);
      puts(array[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```